# How do I find the Inverse of this trig function?

Tags: trigonometry

$\cos(\tan^{-1}(x))$

I set $\tan^{-1}(x)=\theta$, then I found the inverse, which is $\tan(\theta) = x$. That would mean that $\tan(\theta) = \frac{opp}{adj} = \frac{x}{1}$. What I need to do is find the hypotenuse. I know I have to use the Pythagorean theorem, but I don't have the hypotenuse, so it's not possible.

Comment: If you have a right triangle, then the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{x^2+1}$.

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: You have $opp.=x,adj.=1$. What do you get by Pythagoras' theorem? Also, the tag "calculus" is not appropriate - "trigonometry" would be better.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you *know* you have to use Pythagoras' theorem, by the converse of Pythagoras' theorem, the triangle **must** be a right triangle. Thus, since $opp.=x,adj.=1$, drawing out the triangle (if you need to), and using Pythagoras' theorem gives
$$\boxed{Hypotenuse=\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Comment: I understand now. Thank you